# Problems with tables size

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I'm having trouble to insert a table in an article. My article has 2 tables.

I want to put 2 columns length on one table. Which I could achieve, but it is cutting the line.

See the image below.

[image]

The code is:

```
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll|lllll|llll|llll|l|}
\cline{3-16}
                                                                                                   &             & \multicolumn{5}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Compassos com \\ pausas (CV; \%)\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Notas Usadas\\  (NCN)\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{4}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Qualidade das \\ Notas (NQ; \%)\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Razão de Intervalos \\ RI(\%)\end{tabular}} \\
                                                                                                      &             & S             & Pe            & V            & Pi          & C                                & S                  & V                  & Pi                  & C                  & S                     & V                     & Pi                    & C                    & Pe                                                                                         \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Dados de treinamento}                                                                            & 13.06         & 13.06         & 24.4         & 29.8        & 15.1                             & 6.71               & 8.08               & 8.28                & 8.38               & 95                    & 86.9                  & 93.4                  & 94.6                 & 93.6                                                                                       \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{\multirow{4}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Composição\\   do zero\end{tabular}}}   & Simplificado & 97.4          & 100           & 17.5         & 5.68        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5.00}        & 6                  & 7.88               & 7.32                & 9.72               & 5                     & 27.8                  & 36.1                  & 31.2                 & 5                                                                                          \\
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{}                                                                                  & Improviso    & 11.59         & 7.33          & 23.3         & 27.6        & 11.1                             & 6.53               & 8.69               & 9.13                & 9.09               & 76.5                  & 61.6                  & 67.2                  & 68.1                 & 98.2                                                                                       \\
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{}                                                                                  & Compositor   & 5.01          & 33.9          & 6.34         & 5.02        & 5.01                             & 7.51               & 9.2                & 9.89                & 10.19              & 54.5                  & 52.4                  & 54.9                  & 57.5                 & 80.3                                                                                       \\
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{}                                                                                  & Híbrido      & 7.14          & 34.7          & 16.7         & 22.8        & 11.04                            & 7.35               & 9.76               & 10.45               & 10.24              & 49.6                  & 48.2                  & 50.5                  & 57                   & 76.3                                                                                       \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Composição\\ condicional\end{tabular}}} & Improviso    & 9.6           & 8.47          & 18.3         & 15.7        & 8.44                             & 7.05               & 8.79               & 7.12                & 9.23               & 78.9                  & 63.8                  & 64.44                 & 67.3                 & 96.6                                                                                       \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{}                                                                                  & Compositor   & 5.65          & 25.7          & 6.97         & 25.1        & 6.49                             & 7.51               & 9.57               & 6.49                & 10.1               & 58.5                  & 53.4                  & 70.62                 & 64                   & 89.5                                                                                       \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{}                                                                                  & Híbrido      & 7.09          & 9.53          & 15.3         & 28.5        & 9.05                             & 7.86               & 9.43               & 8.33                & 9.32               & 48.3                  & 60.6                  & 72.27                 & 72.1                 & 76.8                                                                                       \\ \hline
\end{tabular*}
```

Comment: Which document class do you employ? Which font, and which font size do you use? How wide is the text block? Which packages need to be loaded to make your code snippet compilable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is just to move a `\\` one place in the last column. However, I will suggest that you set the tabular without nested tabulars using [tabularx](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) and [booktabs](https://ctan.org/pkg/booktabs). See example 2:

**Example 1**

[image]

```
\documentclass[paper=landscape, DIV=15]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{array, multirow}


\begin{document}


\centering

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}ll|lllll|llll|llll|l|}
\cline{3-16}

&
&\multicolumn{5}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Compassos com \\ pausas (CV; \%)\end{tabular}}
&\multicolumn{4}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Notas Usadas\\  (NCN)\end{tabular}}
&\multicolumn{4}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Qualidade das \\ Notas (NQ; \%)\end{tabular}}
&\multicolumn{1}{c|}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Razão de \\Intervalos  RI(\%)\end{tabular}} \\
&             & S             & Pe            & V            & Pi          & C                                & S                  & V                  & Pi                  & C                  & S                     & V                     & Pi                    & C                    & Pe                                                                                         \\ \hline
\multicolumn{2}{|l|}{Dados de treinamento}                                                                            & 13.06         & 13.06         & 24.4         & 29.8        & 15.1                             & 6.71               & 8.08               & 8.28                & 8.38               & 95                    & 86.9                  & 93.4                  & 94.6                 & 93.6                                                                                       \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{\multirow{4}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Composição\\   do zero\end{tabular}}}   & Simplificado & 97.4          & 100           & 17.5         & 5.68        & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{5.00}        & 6                  & 7.88               & 7.32                & 9.72               & 5                     & 27.8                  & 36.1                  & 31.2                 & 5                                                                                          \\
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{}                                                                                  & Improviso    & 11.59         & 7.33          & 23.3         & 27.6        & 11.1                             & 6.53               & 8.69               & 9.13                & 9.09               & 76.5                  & 61.6                  & 67.2                  & 68.1                 & 98.2                                                                                       \\
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{}                                                                                  & Compositor   & 5.01          & 33.9          & 6.34         & 5.02        & 5.01                             & 7.51               & 9.2                & 9.89                & 10.19              & 54.5                  & 52.4                  & 54.9                  & 57.5                 & 80.3                                                                                       \\
\multicolumn{1}{|l}{}                                                                                  & Híbrido      & 7.14          & 34.7          & 16.7         & 22.8        & 11.04                            & 7.35               & 9.76               & 10.45               & 10.24              & 49.6                  & 48.2                  & 50.5                  & 57                   & 76.3                                                                                       \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{\multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}c@{}}Composição\\ condicional\end{tabular}}} & Improviso    & 9.6           & 8.47          & 18.3         & 15.7        & 8.44                             & 7.05               & 8.79               & 7.12                & 9.23               & 78.9                  & 63.8                  & 64.44                 & 67.3                 & 96.6                                                                                       \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{}                                                                                  & Compositor   & 5.65          & 25.7          & 6.97         & 25.1        & 6.49                             & 7.51               & 9.57               & 6.49                & 10.1               & 58.5                  & 53.4                  & 70.62                 & 64                   & 89.5                                                                                       \\
\multicolumn{1}{|c}{}  & Híbrido      & 7.09          & 9.53          & 15.3         & 28.5        & 9.05                             & 7.86               & 9.43               & 8.33                & 9.32               & 48.3                  & 60.6                  & 72.27                 & 72.1                 & 76.8
\\ \hline
\end{tabular*}

\end{document}
```

**Example 2 – tabularx and booktabs**

[image]

```
\documentclass[paper=landscape, DIV=20]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{array, multirow}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs, siunitx, ragged2e}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1cm}}

\begin{document}


\begin{table}
\caption{Adaptive learning rate \emph{etc}.}
\centering\small
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}Ll*{13}{S[table-format=2.2]}S[table-format=2.1]@{}}
\toprule
&
&\multicolumn{5}{P{6.5}}{Compassos \linebreak com pausas (CV; \%)}
&\multicolumn{4}{P{4}}{Notas Usadas \linebreak (NCN)}
&\multicolumn{4}{P{4}}{Qualidade das Notas (NQ; \%)}
&\multicolumn{1}{P{2.6}}{Razão de Intervalos  RI(\%)} \\
\cmidrule(lr){3-7}\cmidrule(lr){8-11}\cmidrule(lr){12-15}\cmidrule(lr){16-16}

& & {$S$} & {$Pe$} & {$V$} & {$Pi$}  & {$C$}  & {$S$}  & {$V$} & {$Pi$}  & {$C$} & {$S$} & {$V$} & {$Pi$} & {$C$}  & {$Pe$}\\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{@{}l}{Dados de treinamento}  & 13.06 & 13.06 & 24.4 & 29.8  & 15.1 & 6.71 & 8.08 & 8.28  & 8.38 & 95  & 86.9  & 93.4  & 94.6 & 93.6 \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{1}{@{}X}{\multirow{4}{=}{Composição\\ do zero}} & Simplificado & 97.4  & 100 & 17.5 & 5.68  & 5.00  & 6  & 7.88 & 7.32  & 9.72 & 5 & 27.8  & 36.1  & 31.2 & 5  \\
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{}  & Improviso  & 11.59 & 7.33  & 23.3 & 27.6  & 11.1 & 6.53 & 8.69 & 9.13  & 9.09 & 76.5  & 61.6  & 67.2  & 68.1 & 98.2 \\
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{}  & Compositor & 5.01  & 33.9  & 6.34 & 5.02  & 5.01 & 7.51 & 9.2  & 9.89  & 10.19  & 54.5  & 52.4  & 54.9  & 57.5 & 80.3 \\
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{}  & Híbrido  & 7.14  & 34.7  & 16.7 & 22.8  & 11.04  & 7.35 & 9.76 & 10.45 & 10.24  & 49.6  & 48.2  & 50.5  & 57 & 76.3 \\ \midrule
\multicolumn{1}{@{}X}{\multirow{3}{=}{Composição\\ condicional}} & Improviso  & 9.6 & 8.47  & 18.3 & 15.7  & 8.44 & 7.05 & 8.79 & 7.12  & 9.23 & 78.9  & 63.8  & 64.44 & 67.3 & 96.6 \\
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{}  & Compositor & 5.65  & 25.7  & 6.97 & 25.1  & 6.49 & 7.51 & 9.57 & 6.49  & 10.1 & 58.5  & 53.4  & 70.62 & 64 & 89.5 \\
\multicolumn{1}{@{}l}{}  & Híbrido  & 7.09  & 9.53  & 15.3 & 28.5  & 9.05 & 7.86 & 9.43 & 8.33  & 9.32 & 48.3  & 60.6  & 72.27 & 72.1 & 76.8
\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to suggest that you (a) give your table a much more open an inviting look by getting rid of all vertical lines, (b) use the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package instead of `\hline` and `\cline`, and (c) align all numbers on their (explicit or implicit) decimal markers with the help of the `S` column type that's provided by the `siunitx` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set page parameters suitably
\usepackage{rotating} % for 'sidewaystable' environment
\usepackage{siunitx}  % for 'S' column type
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable} % switch to landscape format
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}
\sisetup{table-format=2.2}

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} ll *{13}{S} S[table-format=2.1]}
\toprule
& & 
\multicolumn{5}{c}{\begin{tabular}[c]{c}Compassos com \\ pausas (CV; \%)\end{tabular}} & 
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\begin{tabular}[c]{c}Notas Usadas\\ (NCN)\end{tabular}}             & 
\multicolumn{4}{c}{\begin{tabular}[c]{c}Qualidade das \\ Notas (NQ; \%)\end{tabular}}  & 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\begin{tabular}[c]{c}Razão de Inter-\\ valos RI (\%)\end{tabular}} \\
\cmidrule{3-7} \cmidrule{8-11} \cmidrule{12-15} \cmidrule{16-16}
& & {S} & {Pe} & {V} & {Pi} & {C} & {S} & {V} & {Pi} & {C} & {S} & {V} & {Pi} & {C} & {Pe} \\ 
\midrule
\multicolumn{2}{l}{Dados de treinamento} & 
13.06 & 13.06 & 24.4 & 29.8 & 15.1 & 6.71 & 8.08 & 8.28 & 8.38 & 95.0 & 86.9 & 93.4 & 94.6 & 93.6 \\ 
\midrule
\multirow{4}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{l}Composição\\ do zero\end{tabular}} 
& Simplificado & 97.4  &100.0  & 17.5  &  5.68 &  5.00 & 6.0  & 7.88 & 7.32 &  9.72 &  5.0 & 27.8 & 36.1 & 31.2 & 5.0  \\
& Improviso    & 11.59 &  7.33 & 23.3  & 27.6  & 11.1  & 6.53 & 8.69 & 9.13 &  9.09 & 76.5 & 61.6 & 67.2 & 68.1 & 98.2 \\
& Compositor   &  5.01 & 33.9  &  6.34 &  5.02 &  5.01 & 7.51 & 9.2  & 9.89 & 10.19 & 54.5 & 52.4 & 54.9 & 57.5 & 80.3 \\
& Híbrido      &  7.14 & 34.7  & 16.7  & 22.8  & 11.04 & 7.35 & 9.76 &10.45 & 10.24 & 49.6 & 48.2 & 50.5 & 57.0 & 76.3 \\ 
\midrule
\multirow{3}{*}{\begin{tabular}[c]{l}Composição\\ condicional\end{tabular}}
& Improviso & 9.6  &  8.47 & 18.3  & 15.7 & 8.44 & 7.05 & 8.79 & 7.12 &  9.23 & 78.9 & 63.8 & 64.44 & 67.3 & 96.6 \\
& Compositor& 5.65 & 25.7  &  6.97 & 25.1 & 6.49 & 7.51 & 9.57 & 6.49 & 10.1  & 58.5 & 53.4 & 70.62 & 64.0 & 89.5 \\
& Híbrido   & 7.09 &  9.53 & 15.3  & 28.5 & 9.05 & 7.86 & 9.43 & 8.33 &  9.32 & 48.3 & 60.6 & 72.27 & 72.1 & 76.8 \\ 
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Very clever combination of `\tabular*` and `\setlength{\tabcolsept}{0pt}`. You save lots of `@{}`. I have never seen that before!

Comment: @Sveinung - Many thanks for compliment! :-) Setting `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}` when using `tabular*` (along with `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}`) is something I figured out on my own, some time ago; it's definitely not suggested in any LaTeX tutorial I've ever come across. Not only does this save the author from having to type lots of instances of `@{}`, it also saves the author from having to supply left- and right-hand trimming instructions when using `\cmidrule`.