# How to wrap text in tabular

Tags: tables

Since I have multiple column I want to wrap text but can't find suitable code for it. How can I do that in Latex?

I used the following command:

```
\begin{table}
\resizebox{1\textwidth}{!}{
\begin{tabular}{lcccccc} \hline  \hline 
Sample window & Probability cutoff value & Crises Correctly called (\%) & Non-crises correctly called (\%) & Missed crises & False Alarm &  \\ \hline

 \hline
\end{tabular}}
\end{table}
```

And that gives something like below:

[image]

I want to create something like below instead:

[image]

Comment: Don't use `resizebox` on a tablar as this will lead to inconsistent and sometimes illegibly small font sized.

Comment: You might wan to use fixed width  `p` or `m`  type columns instead of `c` columns. If your table will also contain numbers, you might want to ge for `S` type columns from `siunitx` (alignment of numbers)  in combination with `\thead` from `makecell` for the table headers.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12703/how-to-create-fixed-width-table-columns-with-text-raggedright-centered-raggedlef

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](//tex.stackexchange.com/about). Please also go through your previous questions and mark useful answers there, too.

Answer (score 8):

With `\thead` from `makecell` (as I suspect that there will be numbers in the table,  `S` type columns from `siunitx` might come in handy to align them):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\begin{tabular}{lcccccc} 
\toprule
\thead{Sample\\ window} & \thead{Probability\\ cutoff value} & \thead{Crises\\ Correctly\\ called (\%)} & \thead{Non-crises\\ correctly\\ called (\%)} & \thead{Missed\\ crises} & \thead{False\\ Alarm} &  \\ 
\midrule

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

Maybe with `tabularx`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table} 
 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X*{5}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}} 
 \hline \hline 
 Sample window & Probability cutoff value & Crises Correctly called (\%) &
 Non-crises correctly called (\%) & Missed crises & False Alarm  \\ 
 \hline
\end{tabularx} 
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Here's another `tabularx`-based solution, which shows how to set up unequal column widths. Furthermore, it employs the `caption` package to format the appearance of the caption to the style shown in the screenshot, and it employs the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package (`\toprule`, `\midrule`, and `\bottomrule`) instead of `\hline\hline`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash}X}
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\Centering\arraybackslash%
        \hsize=#1\hsize\linewidth=\hsize}X}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{justification=RaggedRight, 
              singlelinecheck=false,
              labelfont=bf,
              labelsep=period,
              skip=0.25\baselineskip}

\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath} % optional

\begin{document}
\setcounter{table}{2} % optional
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{3pt} % default: 6pt
\begin{table}
\caption{Logit EWS: In-sample and out-of-sample performances}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} L *{3}{C{1}} *{2}{C{0.9}} C{1.2} @{}} 
\toprule
Sample windows & Probability cutoff value & 
Crises correctly called (\%) & Non-crises correctly called (\%) & 
Missed crises & False alarms & Crisis prob.\ given alarm \\ 
\midrule
1995--06 & 0.06 & 83.3 & 53.5 & 16.7 & 46.5 & 0.26 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to set up the columns for the data, use `\multicolumn` for the titles.  This divides the columns evenly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}% alignment tool
\newlength{\tempdima}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\tempdima=\dimexpr \textwidth/7 - 2\tabcolsep\relax
\small
\begin{tabular}{lcccccc} \hline\hline 
\multicolumn{1}{p{\tempdima}}{Sample window} & 
\multicolumn{1}{p{\tempdima}}{Probability cutoff value} & 
\multicolumn{1}{p{\tempdima}}{Crises Correctly called (\%)} & 
\multicolumn{1}{p{\tempdima}}{Non-crises correctly called (\%)} & 
\multicolumn{1}{p{\tempdima}}{Missed crises} & 
\multicolumn{1}{p{\tempdima}}{False Alarm} &
\multicolumn{1}{p{\tempdima}}{(not used)}  \\ \hline
 \\
 \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 4):

Here is three different examples on how you can set your tabulars either

1. using [tabularx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx),
2. a combination of [tabularx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) and fixed width `w`-columns from the [array](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/array) packages or
3. a combination of `tabular*` and [dcolumn](https://ctan.org/pkg/dcolumn).

In the two first example and except for the first column, I suggest setting all columns right aligned, also the headings. The are are so dominant so I reduced the font size. As you will see, I aligned all headings at the *bottom* of the cells.

The document class [scrartcl](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/scrartcl) from the [KOMA-script](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/koma-script) has built in commands for setting captions and more sensible margins as standard.

**Example 1 – [tabularx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx)**

I defined three new column types `F`, `R` and `L`, for first column, the seven with decimal separators and the last one.

For the first and last column width, set by the `\hsize=1.2\hsize` it is important that the sum is 2, see the [tabularx manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/tabularx.pdf). Headings are `\footnotesize` to avoid overfull `hbox` warnings.

[image]

```
\documentclass[UKenglish]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs,babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{b{#1}}   % Table headings align at the bottom
\newcolumntype{F}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hsize=1.2\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\bfseries\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash\hsize=0.8\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{R}{>{\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash}X}

\KOMAoptions{captions=tableheading,%
                captions=nooneline}

\addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\small\sffamily\bfseries}
\addtokomafont{caption}{\small\sffamily}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{table}{2} % Increase the couter so next table is table 3
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.4em} % Slightly decrease the space between columns to allow more space for the columns

\begin{table}
\caption{Logit EWS: In-sample and out-of-sample performances}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} F *{7}{R} L @{}}
\toprule
\footnotesize Sample windows &                 % `footnotesize` to avoid overful hboxes
\footnotesize Proba\-bility cutoff value &
\footnotesize Crises correctly called\,(\%) &
\footnotesize Non-crises correctly called\,(\%) &
\footnotesize Missed crises Episodes (\%) &
\footnotesize False alarms &
\footnotesize Crisis prob.\ given alarm &
\footnotesize Crisis prob.\ given no\,alarm &
\footnotesize TME\\ 
\midrule
&&&
\multicolumn{3}{@{}>{\small\Centering\hsize=3\hsize}X@{}}{Panel A: $\eta=2$ \par In-sample}
&&&\\\addlinespace[0.75ex]
1995--06 & 0.06 & 83.3 & 53.5 & 16.7 & 46.5 & 0.26 & 0.06 & 63\\
1995--07 & 0.08 & 73.4 & 61.0 & 26.6 & 39.0 & 0.25 & 0.07 & 66\\ 
1995--08 & 0.07 & 63.4 & 61.4 & 36.6 & 38.6 & 0.29 & 0.13 & 75\\ 
1995--09 & 0.11 & 60.9 & 62.7 & 39.1 & 37.3 & 0.28 & 0.13 & 76\\ 
1995--10 & 0.09 & 60.8 & 59.5 & 33.2 & 40.0 & 0.27 & 0.11 & 74\\ 
\midrule
&&&
\multicolumn{3}{>{\small\Centering\hsize=3\hsize}X}{\small Out-of-sample}
&&&\\\addlinespace[0.75ex]

\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

**Example 2 – [tabularx](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tabularx) and [array](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/array)**

The `w`-column is not a paragraph column, so the headings has to go into `\parbox`es to set the multiline headings. For the seven `w` columns, I use the same fixed width, for the first and last, the `\hsize` picks up the column from [tablarx](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularx), which also ensure that the tabular fills the full line width.

[image]

```
\documentclass[UKenglish]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{babel}

\newcolumntype{F}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hsize=1.2\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\bfseries\RaggedLeft\arraybackslash\hsize=0.8\hsize}X}

\KOMAoptions{captions=tableheading,%
                captions=nooneline}

\addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\small\sffamily\bfseries}
\addtokomafont{caption}{\small\sffamily}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\head}[1]{\parbox[b]{1.35cm}{\RaggedLeft\small #1} }

\setcounter{table}{2} % Increase the table number 
\renewcommand{\tabcolsep}{0.45em} % reduce distance between columns

\begin{table}
\caption{Logit EWS: In-sample and out-of-sample performances}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} F*{7}{wr{1.35cm}}L@{}}
\toprule
\parbox[b]{\hsize}{\small\raggedright Sample windows} &
\head{Probabi\-lity cutoff value} &
\head{Crises correctly called\,(\%)} &
\head{Non-crises correctly called\,(\%)} &
\head{Missed crises \mbox{Episodes} (\%)} &
\head{False alarms} &
\head{Crisis prob.\ given alarm} &
\head{Crisis prob.\ given no alarm} &
\parbox[b]{\hsize}{\RaggedLeft\small TME}\\ 
\midrule
&&&
\multicolumn{3}{wc{4.15cm}}{\parbox{4.15cm}{\Centering\small Panel A: $\eta=2$ \par In-sample}}
&&&\\\addlinespace[0.75ex]
1995--06 & 0.06 & 83.3 & 53.5 & 16.7 & 46.5 & 0.26 & 0.06 & 63\\
1995--07 & 0.08 & 73.4 & 61.0 & 26.6 & 39.0 & 0.25 & 0.07 & 66\\ 
1995--08 & 0.07 & 63.4 & 61.4 & 36.6 & 38.6 & 0.29 & 0.13 & 75\\ 
1995--09 & 0.11 & 60.9 & 62.7 & 39.1 & 37.3 & 0.28 & 0.13 & 76\\ 
1995--10 & 0.09 & 60.8 & 59.5 & 33.2 & 40.0 & 0.27 & 0.11 & 74\\ 
\midrule
&&&
\multicolumn{3}{wc{4.15cm}}{\parbox{4.15cm}{\Centering\small Out-of-sample}}
&&&\\\addlinespace[0.75ex]

\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Example 3 – tabular* and [dcolumn](https://ctan.org/pkg/dcolumn)**

This tabular utilises a combination of zero `\tabcolsep` and `tabular*`’s ability to expand the space between columns stretching the tabular to the given width (here `\linewidth`). [Thanks to Mico for sharing this trick in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/518032/9632).

Since `D`-columns are maths columns, the headings have to be set in  `\multicolumn` to protect them and put the `\parbox` inside those. I defined three different table heading commands (`\thead`), left, centre and right aligned.

The new column types (`Y` and `Z`) are D-columns for one or two decimals.

[image]

```
\documentclass[UKenglish]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{ragged2e,booktabs,babel, dcolumn}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{microtype}

\newcolumntype{Y}{D{.}{.}{1.2}}
\newcolumntype{Z}{D{.}{.}{2.1}}

\KOMAoptions{captions=tableheading,%
                captions=nooneline}

\addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\small\sffamily\bfseries}
\addtokomafont{caption}{\small\sffamily}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{table}{2}       % Increase the counter so next table is table 3
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0em} % Remove tabcolsep, will be compensated by tabular* 
                            % and @{\extracolsep{\fill}}, thanks to Mico
                            % (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/518032/9632)

\begin{table}
\newcommand{\thead}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\parbox[b]{1.35cm}{\Centering\small #1}}}
\newcommand{\theadl}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{l}{\parbox[b]{1.75cm}{\RaggedRight\small #1}}}
\newcommand{\theadr}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{r}{\parbox[b]{1cm}{\bfseries\RaggedLeft\small #1}}}

\caption{Logit EWS: In-sample and out-of-sample performances}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} lY*{4}{Z}*{2}{Y}>{\bfseries}r}
\toprule

\theadl{Sample windows} &
\thead{Probabili\-ty cutoff value} &
\thead{Crises correctly called\,(\%) } &
\thead{Non-crises correctly called\,(\%) } &
\thead{Missed crises Episodes\,(\%)} &
\thead{False alarms} &
\thead{Crisis prob. given alarm} &
\thead{Crisis prob. given no\,alarm} &
\theadr{TME} \\
\midrule
&&&
\multicolumn{3}{@{}>{\small\Centering}p{3cm}@{}}{Panel A: $\eta=2$ \par In-sample}
&&&\\\addlinespace[0.75ex]
1995--06 & 0.06 & 83.3 & 53.5 & 16.7 & 46.5 & 0.26 & 0.06 & 63\\
1995--07 & 0.08 & 73.4 & 61.0 & 26.6 & 39.0 & 0.25 & 0.07 & 66\\ 
1995--08 & 0.07 & 63.4 & 61.4 & 36.6 & 38.6 & 0.29 & 0.13 & 75\\ 
1995--09 & 0.11 & 60.9 & 62.7 & 39.1 & 37.3 & 0.28 & 0.13 & 76\\ 
1995--10 & 0.09 & 60.8 & 59.5 & 33.2 & 40.0 & 0.27 & 0.11 & 74\\ 
\midrule
&&&
\multicolumn{3}{>{\small\Centering}p{3cm}}{Out-of-sample}
&&&\\\addlinespace[0.75ex]

\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```