# Use multiple rows along with vertical centering

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, multirow

I have this code...

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{multirow}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[H]
      \centering
      \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{2cm}|X|m{3cm}|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Participant} & \textbf{Answer} & \textbf{Themes} \\
        \hline\hline
        Short text here & I think I think I think I think I think I think I think I think I think I think I think I think I think I think I think I think I think I think I think I think I think I think I think I think I think I think I think I think & \multirow{5}{*}{Something here} \\
        \hline
        Short text here & test & \\
        \hline
        Short text here & test & \\
        \hline
        Short text here & test & \\
        \hline
        Short text here & test & \\
        \hline
      \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

How can I make themes column take up whole table column without the hline. I still want hline for the other columns. Also vertical center it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to TeX SX! You have to use the `\cline{1-2}`command to ensure the horizontal line stop at the end of the second column. You also have to know that the first argument of the `\multirow` command denotes the number of rows that will replaced by its contents if the rows are single-lined. In other cases, you have to count the number of lines in the adjacent columns (12 in the present case). Furthermore, changing the value af `\arraystretch` makes it more complex, and the best is to estimate the number of equivalent rows and proceed by trial and error – decimal numbers are allowed to fine-tune the position of the centents. Last point: I replaced the `{*}` argument with `{=}` since the third column has a fixed width.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{multirow}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

    \begin{table}[H]
      \centering
      \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{2cm}|X|m{2.5cm}|}
        \hline
        \textbf{Participant} & \textbf{Answer} & \textbf{Themes} \\
        \hline\hline
        Short text here & I think I think I think I think I think I think I think I think I think I think I think I think I think I think I think I think I think I think I think I think I think I think I think I think I think I think I think I think & \multirow{9.5}{=}{Something here} \\
        \cline{1-2}
        Short text here & test & \\
        \cline{1-2}
        Short text here & test & \\
        \cline{1-2}
        Short text here & test & \\
        \cline{1-2}
        Short text here & test & \\
        \hline
      \end{tabularx}
    \end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Do you know that the `w` column is used for and what package provides it like in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/522048/231495? Never heard of it.

Comment: Also is there no automatic solution?

Comment: `w`and `W` are new column specifier for fixed width column, to which you can append a horizontal position specifier, e.g. `wc{2cm}`  is for a horizontally centred column 2cm wide. It comes with recent versions of `array`.

Comment: I'm afraid not, if you have multilined cells in other columns. It is not very long to proceed, though.

Answer (score 1):

The `nicematrix` package by itself provides all the necessary elements for this table. Moreover, the code is clean and simple.

The main command used, `\Block`, allows the identification and format of the multi row/column cells.

(*Important:* The command `\Block{}` creates a monoblock cell that allows the use of `\\` inside, thus cutting the line where you want it instead of relying on the width of the column in left-align text.)

Notice that all cell are (nicely) vertically centered without the need of any manually adjustable parameters, and using natural width of the cell.

[image: ere]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[margin=1.25in]{geometry}
\usepackage{float}
%\usepackage{tabularx}
%\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
%\usepackage{multirow}  

\usepackage{nicematrix}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}    

    \begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    %\begin{NiceTabular}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}p{2cm} l wc{3cm}}[%  use this to retain your original width values
    \begin{NiceTabular}{clc}[%
        cell-space-top-limit = 5pt,
        cell-space-bottom-limit = 5pt,
        hvlines]
        \hline
        \textbf{Participant} & \Block[c]{}{\textbf{Answer}} & \textbf{Themes} \\
        \hline
        Short text here &\Block{}{I think I think I think I think I think \\I think I think I think I think\\ I think I think I think I think I think I think I think \\I think I think I think I think I think I think I think\\ I  think \\I think I think I think I think} & \Block{5-1}{Something here} \\
        Short text here & test & \\
        Short text here & test & \\
        Short text here & test & \\
        Short text here & test & \\
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document
```